# Why is my controller being called twice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-post, sencha-touch

This is probably something simple, but I just can't see it.

I've got my [sencha-touch](/questions/tagged/sencha-touch) application posting data to my WebService ([asp.net-mvc-3](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-3)). The Sencha Touch js code looks like this.

```
var submitCommunicateCard = function () {
    console.log(rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard.getValues());
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: WebService('GetInTouch', 'CommunicateCard'), //http://webservice.example.com/GetInTouch/CommunicateCard
        method: 'post',
        params: {
            callback: 'foo', //temporary until I can better setup the callback.
            name: rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard.getValues().name,
            city: rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard.getValues().city
        }
    });
};
```

Since I need to "thwart" my Cross Site Scripting problems, I've had to write an `ActionFilter` that adds the appropriate headers.

```
namespace WebService.Attributes
{
    public class AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            string rqstMethod = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Method"];
            if (rqstMethod == "OPTIONS" || rqstMethod == "POST")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in my controller, I'm receiving the data from my app as follows.

```
    [AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute]
    public JsonpResult CommunicateCard(CommunicateCardModel communicateCardModel)
    {
        CommunicateCardModel cc = null;
        string rqstMethod = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Method"];
        if (rqstMethod != "POST")
        {
            // Do stuff with the model


             return this.Jsonp(true);
        }
        else { 
            return this.Jsonp(false); 
        }
    }
```

You'll see that I had to put `if (rqstMethod != "POST")` because the model from the "POST" is blank, but the model from the "OPTIONS" is not.

Here are the raw headers being passed... (note: these two headers are being passed in pairs... ie: the controller is being called twice.)

**FIRST CALL**

> OPTIONS /GetInTouch/CommunicateCard HTTP/1.1
>   Host: webservice.example.com
>   Referer: http://192.168.3.138/
>   Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
>   Origin: http://192.168.3.138
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_0) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko)   Chrome/11.0.696.71 Safari/534.24
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type
>   Accept: */*
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
>   Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

**SECOND CALL** *(notice the very bottom line that contains the posted data (which is not contained within the first call) `callback=foo&name=Chester&city=Toronto`)*

> POST /GetInTouch/CommunicateCard HTTP/1.1
>   Host: webservice.example.com
>   Referer: http://192.168.3.138/
>   Content-Length: 38
>   Origin: http://192.168.3.138
>   X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_0) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/11.0.696.71 Safari/534.24
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
>   Accept: */*
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
>   Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
>
> callback=foo&name=Chester&city=Toronto

Is there any way to prevent multiple calls to my controller? (or why IS my controller being called twice?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was fixed by making a JSONP call from my Sencha Touch app.
`Ext.util.JSONP.request`

#### // THIS IS WRONG, DON'T USE THIS CODE TO MAKE JSONP CALLS

```
var submitCommunicateCard = function () {
    console.log(rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard.getValues());
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: WebService('GetInTouch', 'CommunicateCard'), //http://webservice.example.com/GetInTouch/CommunicateCard
        method: 'post',
        params: {
            callback: 'foo', //temporary until I can better setup the callback.
            name: rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard.getValues().name,
            city: rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard.getValues().city
        }
    });
```

#### // THIS IS RIGHT

```
var submitCommunicateCard = function () {
    console.log("Outbound Data Object:");
    console.log(rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard.getValues());
    Ext.util.JSONP.request({
        url: WebService('GetInTouch', 'CommunicateCard'),
        method: 'post',
        callbackKey: 'callback',

        params: {
            name: rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard.getValues().name,
            city: rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard.getValues().city
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            console.log("Inbound Data Object:");
            console.log(result);
            // Handle error logic
            if (result.success === true) {
                Ext.Msg.alert("Sent!", "Thank you, your message has been sent!", Ext.emptyFn);
                rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard.reset();
            } else {
                Ext.Msg.alert("Oops!", "looks like something went wrong, please try again.", Ext.emptyFn);
            }
        }
    });
};
```